# Reaction collector inside of an reaction collector

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a ticket system, and when someone opens a ticket, the bot sends a message and waits for reactions (anyone in the ticket can react to that message). When someone reacts to that message, it disabled the view channel permission for the person that created the ticket (locks the ticket), and sends a new message to which only staff should be able to react. So my problem is that nothing happens when I react to the second message.

Here is the code:

```
const reactionMessage = await channel.send(messageOnTicketCreate)
  
      try {
        await reactionMessage.react("");
      } catch (err) {
        channel.send("Error sending emojis!");
        throw err;
      }
  
      const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
        (reaction, user) => reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user2.id).roles.cache.has(memberid),
        { dispose: true }
      )
  
      collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
        switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
          case "":
            channel.updateOverwrite(user2.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
             const closedTicket = await channel.send(channelLockedMessage)
             const collector1 = closedTicket.createReactionCollector(
              (reaction, user) => reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user2.id).roles.cache.has(supportid),
              { dispose: true }
            )
            
            try {
              await closedTicket.react("");
              await closedTicket.react("⛔");
              await closedTicket.react("");
            } catch (err) {
              channel.send("Error sending emojis!");
              throw err;
            }
            
            collector1.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
              switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case "":
                   channel.updateOverwrite(user2.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true });
                   channel.send(channelUnlockedMessage);
             break;  
              case "⛔":
                channel.send(ticketDeleteMessage);
                setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
                break;
              case "":
                channel.send(ticketTranscript);
                client.commands.get('transcript').run(reaction.message);
                const file = new Discord.MessageAttachment("index.html");
                channel.send(file);
                break;
        
              }
              })
            break;

        }
       })
```

Comment: Where is `user2` from your `<CollectorFilter>`s declared? Shouldn't it just be `user`?

Comment: @Viriato user2 is declared, I just did not show the whole code, only the reaction collector part.

Comment: Could you show its declaration please?

Comment: No need, I have fixed it, it was easier than I thought xD

Comment: Make sure you answer your own question with its solution so other users can help themselves if they're having a similar issue.